# How to deal with "duplicates" in column for prediction

Tags: machine-learning, predictive-models, prediction

**My data** looks like this:

```
|--------------|--------------|--------------|--------------|
|      POS     |     VOLUME   |     LINE     |   SUM_TIME   |
|--------------|--------------|--------------|--------------|
|       1      |      345     |      A       |       5      |
|       2      |      33      |      A       |       6      |
|       2      |      33      |      B       |       4      |
|       3      |      322     |      A       |      20      |
|       4      |      11      |      A       |      11      |
|       4      |      11      |      C       |       4      |
|--------------|--------------|--------------|--------------|
```

That means, I've got `SUM_TIME` for each `LINE` per `POS`, but it is not possible for me to split up `VOLUME` per `LINE` (I only know the `VOLUME` per `POS`). Therefore my only thought is to "duplicate" the `VOLUME` so I dont "loose" the distinction concerning `LINE` and `SUM_TIME`.

My overall **aim** is to predict `SUM_TIME` per `LINE` (there are a lot of other columns like `VOLUME` in my table).

**Question 1**: Does it even make sense to work with all those duplicates in column `volume`?

**Question 2**: Is it "better" to build a prediction model for each `LINE`?

**Question 3**: Is it possible to work with a table like below and somehow predict 3 columns?

```
|--------------|--------------|--------------|--------------|--------------|
|      POS     |     VOLUME   | SUM_TIME_L_A | SUM_TIME_L_B | SUM_TIME_L_C |
|--------------|--------------|--------------|--------------|--------------|
|       1      |      345     |       5      |       0      |       0      |
|       2      |      33      |       6      |       4      |       0      |
|       3      |      322     |      20      |       0      |       0      |
|       4      |      11      |      11      |       0      |       4      |
|--------------|--------------|--------------|--------------|--------------|
```

Comment: Your title is misleading, it appears to refer to the time series forecast, while the body of the question has nothing to do with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your question is bad explained, what you want is to predict sum_time based on pos, volume and line, it does not matter if some values in line are duplicated, it just a categorical value, you have to one-hot encode it to put in you prediction algorithm. If you want more help give more details about type of algorithm, what line means.....

- As far as I have understood your question it makes perfect sense, it is just one categorical value, as long has it is a value that you will have in your test set it is ok
- I do think it is worse to build 3 models, it is more tedious and error prone, I think your model will be able to use the LINE one hot encoded variable to catch the information. The simpler the better.
- Yes, it is possible to build for example a neural network with 3 output neurons, each one of them predicting a different variable